# How to pass complex data types, like records between Ada and C via a DLL?

Tags: c, dll, ada

I am trying to get Ada code to compile to a DLL to be callable in C. So far I have managed to get this to work for simple types such as integers but i'm having difficulty with more complex types such as array's or records/structs.

Below is my Ada code for an record/struct. It is a dynamic library which i compile to a dll using the command "gprbuild -P ./math.gpr -p":

```
person.adb
with Interfaces.C; use Interfaces.C;

package body Person is

   function Set_Age_To_Five(P : Person_Record) return Person_Record is
      Result : Person_Record;
   begin
      Result := P;
      Result.Age := 5;
      return Result;
   end Set_Age_To_Five;

end Person;
```

person.ads

```
with Interfaces.C; use Interfaces.C;

package Person is

   type Person_Record is record
      Name    : String(1 .. 100);
      Age     : Interfaces.C.int;
      Address : String(1 .. 100);
   end record with Convention => C_Pass_By_Copy;

   function Set_Age_To_Five(P : Person_Record) return Person_Record;
   pragma Export (C, Set_Age_To_Five, "Set_Age_To_Five");

end Person;
```

math.gpr

```
library project Math is
    for Languages use ("Ada");
    for Library_Name use "Person";
    for Source_Dirs use ("src");
    for Object_Dir use "obj";
    for Library_Dir use "lib";
    for Library_Kind use "Dynamic";
end Math;
```

I then have a C header file math.h:

```
#ifndef MATH_H
#define MATH_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif

typedef struct {
    char Name[101];
    int Age;
    char Address[101];
} Person_Record;

Person_Record Set_Age_To_Five(Person_Record P);

#ifdef __cplusplus

#endif

#endif /* MATH_H */
```

and finally my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "math.h"

int main() {
    Person_Record p, q, r;

    // Initialize the person record
    snprintf(p.Name, sizeof(p.Name), "John");
    p.Age = 25;
    snprintf(p.Address, sizeof(p.Address), "123 Main St");

    // Call the Set_Age_To_Five function from the DLL
    q = Set_Age_To_Five(p);

    // Print the modified person record
    printf("Name: %s\n", q.Name);
    printf("Age: %d\n", q.Age);
    printf("Address: %s\n", q.Address);

    return 0;
}
```

This should when executed return

```
Name: John
Age: 5
Address: 123 Main St
```

Instead its returning:

```
Name: John
Age: 25
Address: 123 Main St
```

I've tried passing by variable, passing by reference. using convention C and convention pass by c in ada.

Comment: C# interoperability is an entirely separate question.  If that is what you want to do ask about that specifically.  If you want both C and C# interop, ask two separate questions, rather then conflate them here I suggest.  In particular being a .NET language C# interop is likely to be somewhat different than C interop.

Comment: @Clifford I have edited the question to specify ada to C only

Comment: It's odd that your result apparently respects the `Result := P;` assignment, but not the `Result.Age := 5;` assignment.

Comment: Where is [`adainit()`](https://learn.adacore.com/courses/intro-to-embedded-sys-prog/chapters/multi_language_development.html#) called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ADA to C interop of data structures is typically done using pointers, and is likely to be more reliable.

ADA:

```
procedure Set_Age_To_Five (P : in out Person_Record);
pragma Export (C, Set_Age_To_Five, "Set_Age_To_Five");

procedure Set_Age_To_Five (P : in out Person_Record) is
begin
   P.Age := 5;
end Set_Age_To_Five;
```

C:

```
void Set_Age_To_Five(Person_Record *P);
Set_Age_To_Five(&p);
```

I do understand that this is rather less convenient than returning the new struct from ADA, but there seems to be a problem with the way ADA returns the value.  It might have something to do with the fact that ADA uses a different model for  "Pass By Value" than C does.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be explicit about conventions in order to do what C expects about (here) function returns.

This works for me (after telling the C that `struct Person_Record` has 100-character string components; you’ll need to manage the null-termination of those strings somehow):

```ada
   function Set_Age_To_Five(P : Person_Record) return Person_Record
   with
     Convention => C,
     Export,
     External_Name => "Set_Age_To_Five";
```

Answer (score 2):

The fields Name and Address in your Ada record are both strings of 100 characters, whereas they are 101 characters in the C equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Troubleshooting time:

1. Is `Adainit` being called?
2. Did you make sure all the parameter-modes/types were handled?
3. Doesn't the C-code need an "`#extern "C"`" before the line "`Person_Record Set_Age_To_Five(Person_Record P);`" to import the function?
4. Try making the "`Set_Age_To_Five`" return a special value, like `("Dave Smith", -128, "22 Baker St")` and ensure that the value is being propegated/initialized by the function. (You can modify the function to be correct once you have interop.)

And, perhaps a better way to return an element with only a single field different, would be extended return:

```
function Set_Age_To_Five(P : Person_Record) return Person_Record is
begin
  Return Result : Person_Record:= P do
     Result.Age := 5;
  End return;
end Set_Age_To_Five;
```

Hope that helps.